# flask sqlalchemy connection problem error "sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to access mysql database in xampp server using flask_sqlalchemy

my code is as follows

```
from flask import Flask , render_template , request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "secreat key"

app.config['SQLALCHEMY DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:@localhost/cust_51_stock_list'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db =   SQLAlchemy(app)

class Stocks(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    tiker = db.Column(db.String(15))
    price = db.Column(db.String(20))
    qty = db.Column(db.String(20))

    

@app.route('/')
def home():
    tkrs = Stocks.query.all()
    all_data = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
    return render_template('home.html', stk_data=tkrs)

# @app.route('/getdata', methods = ['POST'])
# def send_data():
#     if request.method == 'POST':


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

when I try to access it in html
its showing error "sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table"

where I have database "cust_51_stock_list" and table "stocks"

please help

Comment: Have you created the table(s), as described in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311199/flask-sqlalchemy-operationalerror-sqlite3-operationalerror-no-such-table)?

Comment: yes i have created and there are some rows already

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the tables in the database before you can add models to them. Use `db.create_all()` to do this.